# AndroidStudioによる容量の増加に対して

Tags: android-studio

AndroidStudioを導入しeclipseからの移行をしました。

AndroidStudioの容量は大した事がないのですが、なぜかPCの容量が著しく少なくなってしまったので、確認をしたところ、キャッシュファイルと言われるような

> User/username/.gradle, 
>   User/username/.AndroidStudio1.4,
>   User/username/.AndroidStudio1.5

のファイルが数GBを使っており、特に **.gradleに関しては、20GBを超える容量を有しておりました。**

基本的には必要があるから作っているかとは思うのですが、削除をしてしまいたいと考えていますが、**消すことによる弊害などありましたら教えていただけませんでしょうか。**

また、これ以外にも容量増加の原因になっているようなファイルなどがあれば、削減の方法などご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

私も今確認してみましたが、Android Studio は 1.5.x にアップグレードしてある場合、1.4 の隠しフォルダは削除してもよさそうです（実際に、削除してみましたが、大丈夫そうです）。

.gradle の方ですが、私の環境でも、20GB ほどのサイズで、.gradle/caches がほとんどすべての容量を占めています。cacheなので、削除したとしても致命的な問題にはつながらないと思います。

参考:[How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)

ただし、キャッシュを削除することによるデメリットはあって、次にプロジェクトをビルドする時に、改めて、外部依存ライブラリーをネットワークからダウンロードして組込むという作業が生じることになるので、作業的なオーバーヘッドが生じるので、あまり高頻度では削除しない方がいいと思います。